# Doing stuff in main activity from PreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-preferences

I have this line `info.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, number_config);` below my cases in onItemSelected for a spinner. (it sets the textsize of an EditText with a value set with the spinner) 
Then I have a preferences activity, in which I have a switchpreference, and I would like the above line to be "active" when the switch is set to "On" and inactive when it's set to off. So the textsize does not change when it's set to off. How would you do this?

Thank you very much

My spinners onItemSelected:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                config_textsize = "10.0f".toString();
                break;

            case 1:
                config_textsize = "12.0f".toString();
                break;
                ...
            }

            String number_config = Float.valueOf(config_textsize);
 /*This line */ EditText info.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, number_config);

            }
```

Preferences Activity:

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);  
    }

}
```

This is my switchpreference in xml:

```
  <SwitchPreference
     android:key="EditTextSize"
     android:title="Text Size" 
     android:summary="Change text size when editing" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

this should return true if switched on or false if not. It´s only an assumption, I had never used SwitchPreference, but try it...

### EDIT

create a method which returns integer:

```
    private int getPosition(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
    boolean switchOn = prefs.getBoolean("EditTextSize",
            false);

     int position=-1;

    if(switchOn==false){

         position=0;
     }else if(switchOn==true){

        position=1
       }
    return position;}
```

Comment: see my edit. I hope this works, but without seeing more code, I don´t realy know...

Comment: when setting på class in here: getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this); I get an error saying: No enclosing instance of the type WidgetConfig is accessible in scope

Comment: I never had an error like this...did Yuo replace "YourActivity" with your own activity, I mean, if your Activity is called DemoActivity, You should set "DemoActivity.this".

Comment: see my edit. Create a method which returns position value like in edited Edit. Then call this Method in onItemSelected BEFORE switch. Does this work?